# General error: 1005 Can't create table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

When i run php artisan migrate i keep getting this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>        SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `binomi`.`#sql-3910_c0b` 
>        (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") 
>        (SQL: alter table users add constraint `users_activity_foreign` foreign 
>        key (`activity`) references `activity` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>        [PDOException]
>        SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `binomi`.`#sql-3910_c0b` 
>        (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Here is the **schema** for my user and activity model and those are the only models in the app.

*User migration:*

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('activity');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

  Schema::table('users', function($table){
      $table->foreign('activity')->references('id')->on('activity')->onDelete('cascade');
     }
```

*Activity migration:*

```
 Schema::create('activty', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('label');
    });
```

Comment: Noticed the ";;" at the end of your foreign key line?

Comment: it's just a typing mistake @Duikboot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `unsigned()` modifier to your foreign key column:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->integer('activity')->unsigned();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your activities table has a spelling error, it says `activty` in your schema creation. Also, I would suggest renaming it `activities` unless you only have one.

Comment: i rename it , nothing happened

Comment: Did you also roll things back?

Answer (score 0):

The `increments()` automatically assigned as unsigned.

So, make sure you add unsigned as in the code below:

```
$table->integer('activity')->unsigned();
```

and also check whether you make a typo or not